# Criar e consulta Wp

Tags: php, wordpress, query, phpmyadmin

É possível criar uma tabela no banco de dados do Wp inserir valores e alterar os mesmo, ou ele me bloquearia?
Queria criar uma tabela simples somente para validar, inserir um numero e se necessário fazer a alteração desse numero.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas respondendo ao pé da letra é possível sim, você pode criar uma tabela e alterar seus dados porém se for para manipular os dados dessa tabela pelo painel admin do wp você terá que no mínimo criar um plugin seguindo a arquitetura do wp.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma tabela dentro do banco de dados do Wordpress. Você pode utilizar a função "dbDelta" para criar a estrutura da tabela e a api "wpdb" para o CRUD (Criar, ler, atualizar e deletar ocorrências).

1. Rodar SQL via dbDelta para criar a tabela: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins. Ou, se facilitar, cria a tabela via PHPMyAdmin mesmo.
2. Rodar SQL via $wpdb para inserir, ler, atualizar ou deletar os dados da tabela criada: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Acho que isso deve ajudar.

Comment: Somente uma duvida essa tabela posso editar livremente ?

Comment: Para passar valores so criar dessa forma $value = 1;

Comment: add_option ($ opção, $ value , $ obsoleto =, $ autoload = 'sim');

Comment: Para criar você utilizar: add_option( 'apelido' , 'Leo' ); e então você consulta com o get_option( 'apelido' ); ou altera com o método: update_option( 'apelido', 'Leooooo' );

Comment: Mais como vou conseguir puxar para ter um certeza que isso é um valor verdadeiro para aquele usuário? Pois fazendo dessa forma da a aparecer que consigo ate criar entretanto fica estático o valor e vai ser o mesmo valor a todos, é isso mesmo que acontece?

Comment: O valor é o mesmo para todos os usuários, estático. Essa api deve ser usada para configurações da sua aplicação. Para manipular tabelas customizadas eu alterei a minha resposta. Veja lá se é isso. abs!

Comment: Pode me confirma se eu entendi certo, crio uma variável com comandos sql para a minha estrutura necessária para o meu banco de dados, uso a variavel nativa do wp para isso e para isso funcionar faço o comando add_option, porém isso não vai fazer criar um loop e criar varias tabelas ou não? outra duvida minha estrutura para criar o banco acrescento dentro do fuctions.php mesmo?

Comment: Oi @Fernando, na verdade a api "Options" é outra coisa. Pelo que entendi você vai precisar de mais liberdade para gerenciar os dados, então tem que criar uma tabela mesmo. Você pode criar a tabela via phpmyadmin e depois gerenciar pelo $wpdb (inserir, ler, atualizar, deletar linhas).